# pandas groupby does not count properly. why?

Tags: python, pandas, count, unique, pandas-groupby

When I do the following

`print(dataframe.groupby(['Latitude','Longitude','Year','Day'])['Yield'].unique())`

I get strange result (just a part is shown)

`Latitude   Longitude   Year  Day`  
 
`39.338764  -85.241940  2009  141    [69.9123985]` 
`*                      2010  145    [60.184353, 59.7501973333, 52.523612]` 
`*                      2011  157    [62.324484, 44.512905]` 
`*                      2012  139    [57.240542625]` 
`*                      2013  141    [73.2846975, 67.992009]` 
`*                      2012  139    [55.4780421429]`

where for Year = 2010 and Day = 145 I get three values together 
 
while for Year  = 2012 and Day = 139 I get two separated values which can not be averaged when I apply function mean().

Why?

P.S. it is 0.20.1 pandas version and I do not have any other variables in dataframe

Answer (score 4):

I believe you need `lambda` function with `unique` and `numpy.mean`, because [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.unique.html) return numpy array:

```
print(dataframe.groupby(['Latitude','Longitude','Year','Day'])['Yield'].apply(lambda x: np.mean(x.unique())))
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Latitude':list('aaabab'),
                   'Yield':[1,1,4,5,5,4],
                   'Longitude':list('aaabbb')})

print (df)
  Latitude Longitude  Yield
0        a         a      1
1        a         a      1
2        a         a      4
3        b         b      5
4        a         b      5
5        b         b      4

print(df.groupby(['Latitude','Longitude'])['Yield'].unique())
Latitude  Longitude
a         a            [1, 4]
          b               [5]
b         b            [5, 4]
Name: Yield, dtype: object

print(df.groupby(['Latitude','Longitude'])['Yield'].apply(lambda x: np.mean(x.unique())))
Latitude  Longitude
a         a            2.5
          b            5.0
b         b            4.5
Name: Yield, dtype: float64
```

Alternative solution:

```
print (df.drop_duplicates(['Latitude','Longitude', 'Yield']).groupby(['Latitude','Longitude'])['Yield'].mean())
Latitude  Longitude
a         a            2.5
          b            5.0
b         b            4.5
Name: Yield, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, this gives me exactly the same result

Comment: I tried with upgraded version and still nothing.
Yet my dataset is extracted from the larger one (there were also some other variables), is it possible that pandas has some hidden mask which keeps with the data?

Comment: Yes, it is float64

Comment: Well, I can't share data. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: It does not solve the problem. I am sure that there are no any duplicates in my dataset

Comment: I stated that in the problem description,
"for Year = 2012 and Day = 139 I get two separated values which can not be averaged when I apply function mean()"
it does not give me the average for those two values but instead prints both of them

Comment: I converted dataset file from xls to csv and now it gives me unique values properly.